# Is $H^n(X,A)\cong \tilde{H^n}(X/A)$? for good pair $(X,A)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Is $H^n(X,A)\cong \tilde{H^n}(X/A)$? for good pair $(X,A)$.

I think we can just imitate the method Hatcher used for homology case by the diagram below to get the result. But I don't see the result in any textbook, so I wonder if the claim is always right. 
[image]

Comment: Yes, you can prove this, e.g., using Mayer-Vietoris.

Comment: Alternatively it follows immediately from the UCT and the result for homology.